# In place multiplication of a rectangular and square matrix via Level 3 BLAS

Tags: lapack, blas

I have a large matrix of size *10 Million × 1000*  and I want to compute the result of its multiplication with a square *1000 × 1000* matrix in place.

Currently the level 3 BLAS provides `*trmm` functions which allow us to overwrite the input matrix during multiplication but only if one of the input matrices is triangular. There does not seem to be any such level 3 functionality when the input matrix is a general square matrix instead of triangular.

Now to do my inplace matrix multiplication, I can either do 10Million level 2 BLAS calls to matrix vector multiplication, or I can do a LU decomposition of A and then two level 3 BLAS calls to `*trmm`. I was interested in discussing if there was a third solution that I had overlooked.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist Each column of my matrix needs 10 million floats, and I have 1000 such columns, so the total number of floats is 10 billion, which translates to 40GB memory. My matrix is much larger than your estimate of 8MB, therefore I want to things in place, because even allocating this much memory is time consuming.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist Thanks for the suggestion to split M into the sum of two matrices, unfortunately, I don't think it will work because as soon as I multiply the large matrix , say A, with L, in place, I no longer have a way of computing AU

Comment: I realize my comment was completely in error, so I've scrapped it. Splitting the matrix into `M=L+U` is still a cute idea, but I now believe that your `M=LU` decomposition is the correct way of doing this operation in-place.

Comment: How about performing the multiplication using 1000 rows at a time and calling `dgemm`/`memcpy` 10000 times? Since the mulitplication is not in place, allocating an additional array of size 1000x1000 floats (about 4MB) is required. It's cheap compared to the big array. Nevertheless, the problem of matrix/matrix product is not memory: it takes time...